# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'MyEnum'?

Tags: typescript, enums

I am getting this:

```
error TS2322: Type '{ id: number; status: string; ... }'.
  Types of property 'status' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'MyStatus'.

157     callMethod({ array: [item] })
                             ~~~~
```

where `item = { id: 123, status: MyStatus.Pending }` enum, where `MyStatus.Pending == 'Pending'`.

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

An enum value is not recognised as a string and vice versa, even though the value of them match. You need to set the interface to accept the enum:

```
{ id: number; status: MyStatus; }
```

If you absolutely have to use a string, you can use `as` to get around it, but in all honesty these usually mean you're going against the benefits of TypeScript:

```
item = { id: 123, status: MyStatus.Pending as string }
```

Comment: The schema type definition is generated from GraphQL.

Comment: Then you should use `as`.